# It doesn't take effect when I set the environment variable in the shell script

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

**Purpose**
Set the env global variable in the shell script and then execute the shell script each time to generate a file with a different name
**The code below**

```
#!/bin/bash

# get env value
if [ -z "$PROGRAM_COUNT" ]; then
    export PROGRAM_COUNT=1
fi
count=$PROGRAM_COUNT

count=$((count+1))
# update env value
export PROGRAM_COUNT=$count
echo "================= $PROGRAM_COUNT"

# use env as name
filename="image_$count.gif"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data1/yangyusan/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.12/output/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gdb -ex run --args ffmpeg -i Chn0_20230706_112728_proc0.bmp $filename
```

The result of the printout has been incremented by one.
[printf_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pctth.png)
But After running the script, the environment variable is still 1
[env_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN0V2.png)

**expected outcome**
The environment variable can be incremented by one every time, and the names of the pictures obtained are different

Comment: There is no such thing as global environment variable. Environment is per process. It is inherited only by children processes.

Comment: That is when my shell script finishes, does the environment variable return to its previous value?I don't think so

Comment: It doesn't return to the previous value. It just never changes globally. There are no global environment variables. It changes locally, for that script while it's running. When the script is finished, its local environment is gone.

Comment: You need to manage (in particular increment) the count in the parent script. This is where the initial value of `PARENT_COUNT` comes from.  If this is not feasible, use a file which holds the count (or some other permanent medium).

Comment: You are using `export` for no apparent reason (don't worry, it is extremely common).  At the start of your script, if `PROGRAM_COUNT` is set, then it came from the environment and there is no need to `export` it.  When you assign a new value to PROGRAM_COUNT, it certainly does not need to to exported a second time.   The purpose of `export` is to make the variable available in the environment of any children.  It has no bearing at all on the caller of the script.

Comment: This is exactly how environment variables are _supposed_ to work; it's not a bug in bash, it's a bug in your script to expect anything different.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script it creates an entire environment for that script, including *copies* of any variables from the parent environment, and you can change those - but your changes only happen in your script's environment, and they all evaporate when it ends. The parent environment is not changed.

You CANNOT change the parent environment from a child environment.

If you want a script to call code from another file to change a value in that script, it has to run that code in the current environment, NOT as a child. That means you can't run another script to alter values in your current script directly, but there are some options.

## source the other script

"sourcing" code explicitly mean running it in the current environment with a special syntax, prefixing it with a standalone dot or the word "source". An example:

```
$: cat parent
#! bash
export x=1
echo "parent initial x: '$x'"

echo calling child as subshell script:
./child # creates child environment, can't alter parent value
echo "parent x after subcall: '$x'"

echo calling child as sourced code:
. child # runs in parent environment, has direct access to value
echo "parent x after sourced: '$x'"

$: cat child
#! bash
echo "initial child x: '$x'"
((x++))
echo "child x after increment: '$x'"

$: ./parent
parent initial x: '1'
calling child as subshell script:
initial child x: '1'
child x after increment: '2'
parent x after subcall: '1'
calling child as sourced code:
initial child x: '1'
child x after increment: '2'
parent x after sourced: '2'
```

This is really just reading the `child` file into the current environment and running the commands *as if* they had been a part of the script that is "sourcing" that code.

## create a function

Running a script creates a separate child environment, but a function (by default) doesn't. You must define a function in the environment where you want it to run, though.

```
$: cat func
#! bash
inc() {
  echo "initial func x: '$x'"
  ((x++))
  echo "func x after increment: '$x'"
}
export x=1
echo "parent initial x: '$x'"
inc
echo "parent x after func: '$x'"

$: ./func
parent initial x: '1'
initial func x: '1'
func x after increment: '2'
parent x after func: '2'
```

This code is just an minimal example, and isn't really great programming structure, but you can see that it lets you define a block of repeatable code and apply it in your script.

Note that these techniques are compatible; you can write a function in a file and source it into another script.

```
$: cat parent
#! bash
export x=1
echo "parent initial x: '$x'"
. func
inc
echo "parent x after sourced func: '$x'"

$: cat func
inc() {
  echo "initial func x: '$x'"
  ((x++))
  echo "func x after increment: '$x'"
}

$: ./parent
parent initial x: '1'
initial func x: '1'
func x after increment: '2'
parent x after sourced func: '2'
```

Again, this is a simplistic application, but demonstrates the use.

## capture the stream

A common method is to have the child process send its results as data on the standard output stream - just print it. The parent process can then execute the child and capture that output with *Command Substitution*.

```
$: cat parent
#! bash
export x=1
echo "parent initial x: '$x'"
x=$(./child) # captures child stdout
echo "parent x after reassignment: '$x'"

$: cat child
#! bash
echo "initial child x: '$x'" >&2 # to stderr
((x++))
echo "child x after increment: '$x'" >&2
echo "$x" # to stdout

$: ./parent
parent initial x: '1'
initial child x: '1'
child x after increment: '2'
parent x after reassignment: '2'
```

The child's copy of x is incremented and then sent to stdout.
The parent's copy of x isn't altered **until** the parent explicitly assigns the child's output to the parent copy of x, but the desired result is achieved in a controlled manner.

Comment: If you're interpreting the OP as asking how to persist variables across invocations, we have (lots of) other questions that ask that explicitly; wouldn't it be better to post this answer on one of them, and mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: It would. I reflex to teaching mode from a few years of teaching public high school. It's easier and more fun to answer than do the research and prevent yet another dup, but I need to bear in mind the clutter that results. Thanks for the reminder, will keep working on better habits.